# Letting a user navigate to a /show page under certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I would like a user to be able to get to matchups/:id/show, however, only when they search for the matchup using the site's built-in search functionality, not when they input the url directly in the navigation bar. The search function uses a controller action that finds the matchup they are looking for and `redirects_to` to the matchup's show page.

The reason for this is that users vote on things on the site, and every time they vote they get a credit to spend towards a search. I want them to be able to search for a matchup, but not to navigate to it on their own, therefore avoiding the need to earn credits.

Right now, the search function finds the matchup they are looking for and simply does:

```
redirect_to @matchup
```

so my attempt at putting a before_action filter on the controller's `show` method did not work, because it also prevented the user from accessing the matchup's show page when they did use the search function.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referrer for getting this done. When user enters the URL in the navigation bar, it won't have any referrer.

You can do it in your controller.

```
if request.referer
  #came (probably) from search
else
  #came by entering url in navigation bar
end
```

However, here `request.referer` will exist if user comes from any page rather than search page. If you want to do something ONLY IF they came from search page, you've many options including:

- Add a cookie
- Add a query string to the URL to identify which page it referred from
- You can check in `request.referer` if it matches your acceptable pattern.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks. I will try them out and report back if I end up using one. Thanks again

Comment: Be careful, because the referrer information can be masked or not even returned by a browser. That information was (ab)used in the past and data privacy arguments against its availability can make it unreliable. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3